# Logs not being created when running jar on remote machine via SSH

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, ssh

Assume the following setup:

- MachineA: userA@
- MachineB: userB@

I want to run my JAR on machine B:

When I run it like this:
`java -jar myApplication.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &`
All goes well, and logs are being generated next to my jar file.

When I run it via ssh from machine A:
`ssh userB@<ipB> "java -jar myApplication.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &"`

Application starts on machine B, but no log files are being generated.

Btw, the jar is a regular spring boot application using logback for logging.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is being killed before it even has a chance to create a log file. It will probably work if you remove the final ampersand from your command:

```
ssh userB@<ipB> "java -jar myApplication.jar > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

With the ampersand present, the command is placed into the background. As the shell created by the ssh process has no foreground jobs it immediately closes the connection. When the connection  is closed machine B kills all the command's child processes, including the Java application.

You could also use `nohup` to detach the java process, so that it doesn't get killed when the `ssh` connection closes. This has the added benefit that the application will continue to run even if your connection is interrupted:

```
ssh userB@<ipB> "nohup java -jar myApplication.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &"
```

You might also find it helpful to check out `screen` and `tmux`.

Comment: I have tried that already, and just now again, to check if I haven't missed anything, but no logs are being generated.  
And the application is running, alright. I can easily use its REST interfaces, it's just that no logs are created.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the application was running and the logs were being generated, just not where I had expected.

In myApplication configuration file, there was a property
`logging.file=logs/myApplication.log`

When I was starting my app via SSH, the folder from which was executed was `/home/userB` and not `/home/userB/deployment/build`.
For that reason, logs were not being generated in the same folder where the app was, but in userB's home folder.

The fix was to `cd` to specific folder, before starting the app.